# While catching an error; Getting error.message as INTERNAL in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
requestForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const addRequest = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("addRequest");
addRequest({
  text: requestForm.request.value,
})
  .then(() => {
    requestForm.reset();
    requestForm.querySelector(".error").textContent = "";
    requestModal.classList.remove("open");
  })

   //Error is caused beacuse of this
  .catch((error) => {
    requestForm.querySelector(".error").textContent = error.message;
  });


});
```

Function log errors

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getIteratee (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:5945:25)
    at Function.map (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9580:31)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:177:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13427:38
    at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
    at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13426:7)
    at encode (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:183:18)
    at arrayMap (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:639:23)
    at Function.map (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9580:14) 
addRequest
Function execution took 309 ms, finished with status code: 500
```

*The function was supposed to check for normal HTTPS errrors in firebase like "unauthenticated" and "invalid-argument" but got **INTERNAL** ERROR instead*

While doing firebase serve its still catching the error
But with firebase deploy its not even going inside the catch function
Its showing error.message as "INTERNAL"?
What does that mean

Comment: It means you should look at the functions log in the Firebase console.

Comment: Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. finished with status code: 500 Its showing these? What can I do now

Comment: You should edit the question to show all of your observations, especially the code that isn't working the way you expect.  There should be enough information here so that anyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may find assistance here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact